# Loop over a list in order to apply the same function to multiple Datasets

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops, oop

I'm looking for a way to apply a funtion to multiple rdds (rdd : A Resilient Distributed Dataset). I'm using PySpark and I have to get 6 new rdds by applying the same function to all of my original Datasets. I have something like this :

```
def define_CohortPeriods(d_date):

    do something

    return something

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:

       first_OrderPeriod = define_CohortPeriods(d_date = '2016-10-19')
       second_OrderPeriod = define_CohortPeriods(d_date = '2016-10-20')
       third_OrderPeriod = define_CohortPeriods(d_date = '2016-10-21')
       fourth_OrderPeriod = define_CohortPeriods(d_date = '2016-10-22')
       fifth_OrderPeriod = define_CohortPeriods(d_date = '2016-10-23')
       sixth_OrderPeriod = define_CohortPeriods(d_date = '2016-10-24')


   except ValueError:

       print "Error"
```

I want to just give two arguments to my code, for exemple the first and the last date, and do something like this :

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td

first_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-19', '%Y-%m-%d')
last_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-24', '%Y-%m-%d')

deltaDate = last_date - first_date

for i in range(deltaDate.days + 1):

    print d1 + td(days=i)
```

which gives :

```
2016-10-19 00:00:00
2016-10-20 00:00:00
2016-10-21 00:00:00
2016-10-22 00:00:00
2016-10-23 00:00:00
2016-10-24 00:00:00
```

And finally, iterate through this list of dates, associate every time a date to d_date, and get separately my expected outputs : first_OrderPeriod, second_OrderPeriod, third_OrderPeriod, etc.

What is the most efficient way to do this ? Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to store your `orderPeriod` values and then access them by index.  Since we're storing them in a list, we can use a list comprehension to build that list.

```
dates_list = [d1 + td(days=i) for i in range(deltaDate.days +1)]
orderPeriods = [define_CohortPeriods(d_date) for d_date in dates_list]
```

It's not quite clear whether `define_CohortPeriods` accepts strings or `datetime` objects.  You should probably be using `date` objects for both though, as you aren't using the `time` part of the `datetime` object.